# Property of derived set

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading real analysis where i encountered a line related to derived sets which i am unable to prove on my own.

**Statement** - `If a set 'S' is of first species , then its last derived set must be empty.`

Just to mention here the following :-

1. A set is said to be of first species if it has only a finite number of derived sets.
2. The set of all limit points of a subset 'S' of ℝ  is called the derived set of that subset.

Possible approaches - We can assume that lets say the last subset of the subset 'S' is not empty (we can call it X). Then it can either be finite or infinite .

The last derived set cannot be finite because that would mean that the derived set of this set exists which is ∅ , hence making our derived set X not the last derived set on the list.

How do i go about proving the same if X is infinite ? Any other approaches are welcome.

Comment: If $S'$ denotes the derived set of $S$, then I'm assuming the derived *sets* are $S', S'', S''', S'''', \ldots$. In that case the statement is false since $\Bbb{R}$ is of first species because $\Bbb{R} = \Bbb{R}' = \Bbb{R}'' = \cdots $ but $\Bbb{R} \ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Your definition of "first species" doesn't seem accurate. The closed interval $[0,1]$ is its own derived set, so no matter how many times you iterate "derived set" you get just one set, $[0,1]$. That makes $[0,1]$ a set of first species by the definition in the question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass , your argument is strong. Can you provide the correct definition of 'first species' and whether the statement is correct or not ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never heard the terminology "first species" before, so I don't know what it's intended to mean or to do. And googling "`first species' math" doesn't help either.

Comment: @Andreas Blass: The term "first species" is an older term (see p. 71 of Volume I of [Hobson's treatise](https://archive.org/details/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich/page/n91/mode/2up)) that refers to sets, usually in $\mathbb R$ or ${\mathbb R}^n,$ having a finite Cantor-Bendixson rank. The notion itself is due to Cantor, and I suspect also the name (when appropriately translated from German) is due to Cantor, who used the notion as a first step in proving some trigonometric series uniqueness results (see my comments [to this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/361890/15780)). **(continued)**

Comment: The notion was applied by a few mathematicians in the late 1880s for certain fairly specialized results (often results that were later generalized to arbitrary countable sets, but perhaps not always), primarily Dini I think, who used the notion quite a bit in his 1878 real variable treatise mentioned in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/376119/15780).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro I suspected this might be the intended meaning, but then  the usual definition of Cantor-Bendixson rank, as the number of iterations of "derived set" to get to $\varnothing$, would make the statement in this question true just by definition.

Comment: Yes, and I wasn't sure what to make of the OP's question, which is why I didn't say anything. I think the OP probably needs to provide a bit more context, although this might be difficult because that context might have been in lecture and not fully comprehended, and thus is part of what is needed to provide an answer to the OP. (Harsh Vardhan Singh: OP is a common abbreviation for "original poster", so "OP" refers to you.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks sir for the response .Actually , I was reading and solving real analysis notes . While going through the foundations of the course , i came to this part of the course describing definitions like 'first species', 'second species' , 'derived sets'.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro , Sir, what do you think of the example mentioned by Andreas as [0,1] .Is he correct ?

Comment: I think the definition and statement are a bit carelessly worded, and if this is from a person and not a published source, then you should seek clarification from that person. The usual **definition** of "first species" is that for some finite number $n,$ the set's $n$-th derived set is empty.

Comment: Sir , then by this definition , i can say that the set [0,1] doesn't come under 'finite species' ? Thanks for mentioning the definition though, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Andreas Blass and OP: Of possible interest is [*How did Cantor Discover Set Theory and Topology?*](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/019/11/0977-0999) by Sashi Mohan Srivastava (2014; first species mentioned on p. 984) and the [January 1893 Bull. AMS review by James Harkness (1864-1923) of the 1892 German version of Dini's book](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1893-02-04/S0002-9904-1893-00111-0/S0002-9904-1893-00111-0.pdf) (first species mentioned on p. 73).

Comment: To summarize for OP: Under the definition provided by @DaveL.Renfro (and the references he cites), $[0,1]$ is not of first species, and the statement you wanted to prove is true by definition.  Under the definition that you provided in the question, $[0,1]$ is of first species, and the statement you wanted to prove is false. (Perhaps the author of the notes you used intended yet another definition.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass sorry to bother 4 months later but I have a question about the derived set , if we take for example the set $A = $ ($0,1$) using the upper limit topology the derived set should be : $A' = $($0,1$]  ? Am I right ?

Comment: @EmmaFlora If "upper limit topology" means what I think it does (generated by the basis consisting of half-open intervals $(a,b]$) then yes, you're right.